# Rails engine depends on another engine, where to add dependecy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

I'm building a mountable engine that is dependent on another 'core' (unmounted) engine that I have written.

In my container app's Gemfile I add the core engine and the optional engine's git repo's.

In my mountable engine, where should I add its dependencies on the 'core' engine to be used in the dummy app for testing? (rspec)

I tried adding this in the mountable engine's gemspec:

```
require "my_core"
...
s.add_dependency "my_core", :git => "https//github.com/me/my_core.git"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am doing this by declaring the dependency in the engine Gemfile

```
if ENV['LOAD_GEMS_FROM_LOCAL'] == '1'
    gem 'my_core', path: File.expand_path("../../my_core", __FILE__)
else
    gem 'my_core', git: 'https//github.com/me/my_core.git'
end
```

The LOAD_GEMS_FROM_LOCAL lets me load the other engine from the filesystem, so I can develop both engines at the same time.

Comment: Yes I added it to the engine's Gemfile and at the top of engine.rb added require 'my_core/engine' http://yehudakatz.com/2010/12/16/clarifying-the-roles-of-the-gemspec-and-gemfile/